# How to run a command on only the first instance in a specific layer on deployment with opsworks?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

We are deploying a Laravel application on aws opsworks, everything is running great, however we need to do two other things:

1) On each deployment we want to run `php artisan migrate` to install the database updates.
2) We have a file (app/database/run.list) which contains a list of class names, for each line in the file we want to run `php artisan db:seed --class={line from file}`.
e.g.

run.list contains

```
NewSystemSeed
NewUserSeed
CreateDefaultTemplatesSeed
```

we want to run

```
php artisan db:seed --class=NewSystemSeed
php artisan db:seed --class=NewUserSeed
php artisan db:seed --class=CreateDefaultTemplatesSeed
```

That parts not exactly difficult (although I am a bit stuck on the last one).
The part that I am stuck on is, we only want to do this on the first instance in a specific layer (the php-app layer).

We obviously don't want to end up seeding the database for every instance!

Is there a way to automate this, or must we create another recipe, then after deployment manually trigger this recipe on the instance?

Comment: Note, I wasn't sure if SO was the best SE site for this question, so if there is a better site for devops related questions please let me know!

Comment: Great question. Could you write something to the database when the seeder runs and check for it on startup? That way, the other servers would see the flag and skip the seed.

Comment: @ceejayoz, that's pretty much what the migrations do, we could theoretically write out our seeds as migrations, but our seeds are usually written idempotent so say we wanted to update the list of roles, our seed would wipe out all the roles and insert every one of them again, so they are reusable.

Comment: I know in elastic beanstalk with the ebextensions there is the leader_only concept which would be perfect..

Answer (score 2):

Rather than put one of your instances in a special layer, which creates a single point of failure if that instance goes down, you could choose the first instance from the list of Opsworks instances in your app layer and always do your migrations there. This allows you to keep your configuration as-is and ensures that you always run the migrations on a running instance since failed instances won't be in the list.

```
migrations_instance_hostname = node[:opsworks][:layers]['app-layer'][:instances].keys.sort.first

if migrations_instance_hostname == node[:opsworks][:instance][:hostname]
  # do migrations
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Layers as tags in OpsWorks to signal recipes.

Create a new Layer (perhaps "db-seeder"). Instead of adding a new instance in that layer, add an existing instance from your PHP layer.

Create a new custom recipe that looks like this:

```
if node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?("db-seeder")
  config_file = 'app/database/run.list'
  bash "migrate db" do
    code %Q^
      php artisan migrate
      for clz in `cat #{config_file}` do;
        php artisan db::seed --class=${clz};
      done^
  end
end
```

The above recipe will only operate on an instance that is in the "db-seeder" Layer.
Add this custom recipe to the "deploy" event for the PHP app layer.